# Facebook login button on iPhone

Tags: iphone, facebook, mobile, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-oauth

I'm using the Facebook JS SDK for my website's login and I have this code on my page

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({"appId":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxx","xfbml":true,"oauth":true,"status":false,"cookie":true,"logging":false});
        onFbInit();
    };

    (function() {
        var e = document.createElement('script'); 
        e.src = document.location.protocol + "\/\/connect.facebook.net\/en_US\/all.js";
        e.async = true;
        document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
    }());
</script>

    <fb:login-button scope="email" autologoutlink="false">Log in using Facebook</fb:login-button>

<script>
    function goLogIn(){
        window.location = "/fb/login_check";
    }

    function onFbInit() {.
        if (typeof(FB)!= 'undefined' && FB!= null ) {
            FB.Event.subscribe('auth.statusChange', function(response) {
                setTimeout(goLogIn, 500);
            });
        }
    }
</script>
```

This works fine on all desktop browsers and iPad, but on Mobile Safari on iPhone/iPod the login button opens a new tab but does not post back to the page and therefore callback is not called. When I click the Facebook login button on my login (or register) page, it opens the Facebook oauth login page in a new tab, I enter my Facebook login details and the Facebook tab closes but the focus does not return back to my login page. I don't have a Mac to use the inspector but a friend says that they got this error in the debug console "Unable to post message to https://m.facebook.com/. Recipient has origin https://www.facebook.com/"

To reproduce the steps:

1. Go to http://eventstagr.am/register on iPhone (Safari Mobile and Chrome both don't work)
2. Click register

   - **EXPECTED**: The Facebook tab should close and call the javascript callback function on the register page
   - **ACTUAL**: The Facebook tab closes and focus does not return to the register page

Alternatively if you already have an account, repeat the steps above but from http://eventstagr.am/login, the results are the same.

Comment: This bug has been fixed now http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/395093920559749

Answer (score 0):

Have you registered your app for mobile web login? You can do this ([per Facebook's instructions](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/login-for-mobile-web/)) by going into the [Facebook app settings](http://developers.facebook.com/apps/).